# Unable to use variables assigned inside getText() function outside of get text even after declaring them globally in Nightwatch.js

Tags: javascript, variables, asynchronous, global, nightwatch.js

I have code like below where an iterating loop inside elements functions and using getText() for fetching data and storing it in an object then pushing into an array. I have declared an object and array globally but unable to use outside of getText() and elements() as well.

My code staructure:

```
const successFromUI = {
    cmoId: '',
    status: '',
};
const cmoArray = [];
exports.command = function SaveCMOsWindowValidation(cpoID) {
    this.perform(function a() {
        let cpoIDS = cpoID;
        this.api.elements('css selector', editorSelectors.editorFields.massEditSaveRows, function avilableRows(res) {
            for (let y = 0; y < res.value.length; y++) { // Iterating loop on the list of values in table to to fetch values required.
                const childStatus = editorSelectors.editorFields.massEditSaveWindowChildFirstPart + (y + 1) + editorSelectors.editorFields.massEditSaveWindowStatusSecondPart;
                const childCMO = editorSelectors.editorFields.massEditSaveWindowChildFirstPart + (y + 1) + editorSelectors.editorFields.massEditSaveWindowCMOIDSecondPart;
                this.pause(2000);
                this.getText(childCMO, function getCMOID(ID) {
                    successFromUI.cmoId = ID.value;
                    console.log('Inside cmo on ui' + successFromUI.cmoId);
                    this.getText(childStatus, function getStatus(status) {
                        successFromUI.status = status.value;
                        console.log('Inside status on ui' + successFromUI.status);
                        cmoArray.push(successFromUI);
                        console.log('Inside ' + successFromUI);
                        console.log('Inside ' + cmoArray[y].status);
                        console.log('Inside ' + cmoArray[y].cmoId);
                        console.log('length of array inside ' + cmoArray.length);
                    });
                });
            }// Outside of for loop and outside of getText() functions those variables are not getting accessed
            console.log('Outside ' + successFromUI[0].cmoId); // no val
            console.log('Outside ' + successFromUI[1].status); // no val
            // console.log('outside ' + cmoArray[0].status);
            // console.log('outside ' + cmoArray[0].cmoId);
            // console.log('outside ' + cmoArray[1].status);
            // console.log('outside ' + cmoArray[1].cmoId);
            for (let len = 0; len < cmoArray.length; len++) { // No results
                console.log('Array outside of for loop' + cmoArray[len]);
            }
        }); // end of elements function
    }); //end of perform function
};
```

Can anyone tell me how to resolve this issue in nightwatch.js.

How can I use those variables globally outside of those functions. Even my console statements gets executed first than the actual code inside elements and getText functions. Is there any way to overcome this asynchronous behavior?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: successFromUI is not an array, is an object, so you can't do successFromUI[0]

Comment: Hope this is correct then calling array and its object , but it is also not working.
            console.log('outside ' + cmoArray[0].status);
            console.log('outside ' + cmoArray[0].cmoId);
            console.log('outside ' + cmoArray[1].status);
            console.log('outside ' + cmoArray[1].cmoId);

Comment: for (let len = 0; len < cmoArray.length; len++) { // No results
                console.log('Array outside of for loop' + cmoArray[len]);
            } Even this part of code did not gave any results. can you please help me how to access them correctly if am making any mistake in my coide.